# Copy Row if Sheet1 A contains part of Sheet2 C

Tags: rss, google-sheets, google-docs, drive, advanced-search

So I'm trying to pull the data in a row from a separate sheet (sheet2!), if part of Col A has the the Date that is in sheet1! C1.

Col A ex: "Build 251 at Fri Jun 12 03:03:49 2015"

Col C1 ex: "Fri Jun 12" (Changes date every couple days)

I've tried these formulas but they don't work. The errors I get back are "finished with no results"; "error filter has mismatched range sizes"; "there is no ColumnA"; "formula parse error"

`=filter("'GitHub-Changelog'!A", ("'GitHub-Changelog'!A" = 'x64 RSS Data'!C2))`

`=QUERY('GitHub-Changelog'!A:F,"select * where A contains '(TRANSPOSE(" "&C1:C&" "))'")`

`=FILTER('GitHub Changelog'!A,MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&'x64 RSS Data'!C1:C&" ")," "&'GitHub-Changelog'!A1:A&" "),SIGN(ROW('GitHub-Changelog'!A1:A))))`

I'm not sure why I'm not getting results, the date is in A. If I use this `=QUERY('GitHub-Changelog'!A:F,"select * where A contains 'Fri Jun 12'")` It prints out the single row, it's just not reading C1 for some reason; and I need it to be dynamic to match whatever C1 changes to.

*The true future ideal goal would be to check Sheet1!C against Sheet2!A, if part of A contains C then copy whole row (Sheet2!A:F) into a single cell (Sheet1!E). Along the lines of `IF Sheet2!A contains sheet1!C1 then copy (sheet1!E=Sheet2!D&C&B`, but I believe that needs full script writing to accomplish this so I'm not sure how to do it yet, but will learn; one thing at a time though (just thought I'd share a better version of what I'm trying to accomplish).

Here is the sheet I'm working on: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPOwiYGBK0kSJXXU9kaQjG7WNHjnNuxy25WCUudE5sk/edit?usp=sharing`. It pulls multiple pages on different sheets, then cleanup pages of the data. The plan is to have an update sheet that searches the changelog info for the date of the current build and puts that data next the build. So the final sheet will show most recent build + commit changes for that nightly build. That's where this function is being used, to scrape the changelog for the same date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
=query('GitHub-Changelog'!A:F; "where A contains '"&C1&"' ")
```

where C1 (on the same sheet as the formula) is the cell that holds the date (ex: Fri Jun 12).

Comment: So I don't need `select*` in the formula, just query?

Comment: Here is the sheet I'm working on: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPOwiYGBK0kSJXXU9kaQjG7WNHjnNuxy25WCUudE5sk`. It pulls multiple pages on different sheets, then cleanup pages of the data. The plan is to have an update sheet that searches the changelog info for the date of the current build and puts that data next the build. So the final sheet will show most recent build + commit changes for that nightly build. That's where this function is being used, to scrape the changelog for the same date.

Comment: I can't open that file. Can you add a link in your post ?

Comment: Added the link to the post. Not sure why it doesn't work in the comments

Comment: Hi, the value in D1 is a numeric value. Try converting it to text like this: =query('GitHub-Changelog'!A:F, "where A contains '"&to_text(D1)&"' ")

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to surround the range with "".

Also, you can use **Find()** in your filter, to check if that date is present in the string.

Here is a working Filter formula:

```
=FILTER('GitHub-Changelog'!A:F, Find('x64 RSS Data'!C1,'GitHub-Changelog'!A:A))
```